# NoSuchMethodError error for getActionBar() (API-8)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

when i run the app it installs but then crashes, ecplise isnt telling there is anything wrong with my code.
i think its a problem with my manifest...

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.secondapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>                
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value="com.example.secondapp" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

do u guys see any problems?

```
10-19 10:41:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10147): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 10:41:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10147): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.secondapp.MainActivity.getActionBar
10-19 10:41:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10147):    at com.example.secondapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
10-19 10:41:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10147):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-19 10:41:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10147):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
10-19 10:41:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10147):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
10-19 10:41:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10147):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-19 10:41:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10147):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
10-19 10:41:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10147):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-19 10:41:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10147):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-19 10:41:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10147):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
10-19 10:41:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10147):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 10:41:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10147):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-19 10:41:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10147):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
10-19 10:41:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10147):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
10-19 10:41:25.589: E/AndroidRuntime(10147):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is the logcat, not sure if this will help

Comment: What is the code of the line 15 in `MainActivity`?

Comment: Aparently MainActivity doesn't have the method `getActionBar()`. Post you MainActivity code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183461/android-solving-compatibility-with-sdk-int-hack-is-this-ok. This may be of help to you.

Answer (score 18):

Use `getSupportActionBar` available with support library v7 as described [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html) on the `6. Retrieve the Action Bar` section

[getSupportActionBar documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#getSupportActionBar%28%29)

Answer (score 9):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.secondapp.MainActivity.getActionBar

On your MainActivity class, you call `getActionBar()` which is not available to your application.

Your `android:minSdkVersion` is set to 8 (API-8), which does not provide `getActionBar()` (only since API-11).

You should use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) for good backward compatibility, or set `android:minSdkVersion` but then all devices < API-11 won't be targeted.

Comment: Is the Android lint failing to catch this ? If his "android:minSdkVersion" is right then the lint should throw an error right ?

Comment: @Tarantula I don't think so. Maybe a SuppressWarning or something. Anyway, that is the error I think

Comment: As other (less voted) answers suggest, you just need to add compatility feature and use getSupportActionBar() instead.

Answer (score 9):

This is because the `getActionBar` is a method of api 11, but you can do this:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //example
```

and in the activity class add this suppress Lint:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
```

Answer (score 6):

I faced this same issue before. I just replace

```
getActionBar()
```

with

```
getSupportActionBar()
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably running on a phone that is lower than API 11, which is when the method `getActionBar` was introduced. If you need to run on devices lower than API level 11, then you will need to guard against executing those calls that only exist on newer API levels, or else use a compatibility library such as [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) or [Action Bar Compatiblity](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html). (See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844517/different-between-actionbarsherlock-and-action-bar-compatibility) for a discussion of the differences between these two.)

Change the `android:minSdkVersion="8"` to `android:minSdkVersion="11"` and all the newer API calls that you are making will light up as errors. This will make it easier to locate those parts of your code that need attention.

Comment: Changing `android:minSdkVersion` will prevent its application from running for devices < API 11

Comment: @shkschneider - Well, yes. If OP doesn't use a compatibility library (such as ActionBarSherlock), then the app won't run on pre-11 devices. The purpose of changing the minSdkVersion is to make it easy to find all the places where the code contains calls that need attention.

Comment: Note that even if you use a compatibility library (specifically ActionBarSherlock) you may still get this error.

Comment: @dpk - That's surprising. Under what circumstances will the error still show up (for calling `getActionBar`) when using the compatibility library?

Comment: @TedHopp Not exactly sure, but I was using ActionBarSherlock and getActionBar() was throwing NoSuchMethodError. I switched to getSupportActionBar() and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

For api < 11 you have to use:

```
getSupportActionBar();
```

Algo make sure you are using appcompat, add this on build.gradle, the 19.+ should be your project target version.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
```

Also if you are using invalidateOptionsMenu() for **navigation drawer** use this instead:

```
supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
```